# Beamer: Table of Contents: Setcounter

Tags: beamer

[image]

Q. How do I get this output in a beamer type of document

Answer (score 2):

The same way you do it for any document, add:

```
\tableofcontents
```

in the frame you want to show the TOC.

Comment: by default it would begin with 1. how to reset it o 7?

Comment: `\setcounter{chapter}{7}` or `\setcounter{section}{7}` depending what you want to change.

Comment: @SalatielGarcia ... it is `\setcounter{section}{6}` just before the `\section{}` command ... And there are no `\chapter`s in beamer by default.... But +1 anyway for the help you provided